# Laravel fullcalendar ошибка moment.js

Tags: laravel5, fullcalendar

Пытаюсь подключить fullcalendar (https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar) и в консоли выскакивает ошибка

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
```

Мой контроллер:

```
$lessons = Lesson::where('date_end','>',now())->get();
      $events = [];
      foreach ($lessons as $lesson) {
        $events[] = Calendar::event(
              $lesson->theme, //event title
              true, //full day event?
              $lesson->date_start, //start time,
              $lesson->date_end, //end time,
              null,
              // Add color and link on event
            [
                'color' => '#f05050',
                // 'url' => 'pass here url and any route',
            ]
          );
      }
      $calendar = Calendar::addEvents($events);
```

Дата в формате Y-m-d H:i:s

Подключаю fullcalendar 4.0.2

```
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- moment -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('js/moment.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- fullcalendar -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('js/fullcalendar.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: Попробуйте перевести текст ошибки

Comment: Написано же, что `moment().zone` устаревший метод, вместо него юзай `moment().utcOffset`.

Comment: `moment().tz(...)`  замените на `moment.tz(...)` или так ещё можно -> `moment(Date.now()).tz(...)` там где формат указываете

Comment: Я изменил вопрос. Спасибо за помощь, но теперь другая проблема(

Answer (score 0):

Загрузил CDN версию и все заработало. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.0/fullcalendar.min.js`